# Selecting the default open row in an accordion

Tags: javascript

I am trying to setup a page with an accordion, in which I can change which row is opened by default, every quarter. This is done in a Sharepoint site, so I'm somewhat limited on what I can do.

The code uses the Sharepoint webpart titles to pull the HTML coding from which they display their content. I did not write this code, I copied/modified it from Mark Rackley's "Hillbilly tabs" website.

Here is the Javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
         //Put the WebPart Title for all the Web Parts you wish
         //to put into the jQuery UI Accordion into the array below.
        Hillbillyaccordion(["FY18Q4","FY19Q1","FY19Q2"]);
    });

    function Hillbillyaccordion(webPartTitles)
    {
        for(index in webPartTitles)
        {
            var title = webPartTitles[index];
            $("#accordion").append('<h3>'+title+'</h3>');
            $("span:contains('"+title+"')").each(function(){
                if ($(this).text() == title){
                    var webPart = $(this).hide().closest("span").closest("[id^='MSOZoneCell_WebPart']");
                    if ($(webPart).contents().html() != undefined)
                    {
                         webPart = $(webPart).contents();
                    }
                    $("#accordion").append(webPart);
                }
            });
        }
        $("#accordion").accordion({ heightStyle: "content" });
    }


</script>
<div id="accordion"></div>
```

The HTML:

```
<table class="ms-rteTable-0" cellspacing="0" style="width: 65%;">
   <tbody>
      <tr>
         <td class="ms-rteTable-0" style="width: 100%;"> 
            <div class="ms-rtestate-read ms-rte-wpbox" contenteditable="false">
               <div class="ms-rtestate-notify  ms-rtestate-read f0bd8512-73d2-4d90-822d-23db740f5665" id="div_f0bd8512-73d2-4d90-822d-23db740f5665" unselectable="on">
               </div>
               <div id="vid_f0bd8512-73d2-4d90-822d-23db740f5665" unselectable="on" style="display: none;">
               </div>
            </div>
            <div class="ms-rtestate-read ms-rte-wpbox" contenteditable="false">
               <div class="ms-rtestate-notify  ms-rtestate-read 5fc7f31f-65af-432a-8b21-10c760226ccf" id="div_5fc7f31f-65af-432a-8b21-10c760226ccf" unselectable="on">
               </div>
               <div id="vid_5fc7f31f-65af-432a-8b21-10c760226ccf" unselectable="on" style="display: none;">
               </div>
            </div>
            <div class="ms-rtestate-read ms-rte-wpbox" contenteditable="false">
               <div class="ms-rtestate-notify  ms-rtestate-read 5233fd78-4eff-410c-a3df-eedf46f80376" id="div_5233fd78-4eff-410c-a3df-eedf46f80376" unselectable="on">
               </div>
               <div id="vid_5233fd78-4eff-410c-a3df-eedf46f80376" unselectable="on" style="display: none;">
               </div>
            </div>
            <p>
               <br/>&#160;</p>
            <div class="ms-rtestate-read ms-rte-wpbox" contenteditable="false">
               <div class="ms-rtestate-notify  ms-rtestate-read 2783a954-2339-4353-b420-63a2dd92b0e5" id="div_2783a954-2339-4353-b420-63a2dd92b0e5" unselectable="on">
               </div>
               <div id="vid_2783a954-2339-4353-b420-63a2dd92b0e5" unselectable="on" style="display: none;">
               </div>
            </div> ​</td>
      </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

So in this case, I would like the FY19Q1 row to be open by default. Right now, the FY18Q4 is the one that opens (And closes when I click elsewhere).

Would like any tips or help. Thank you.

Comment: It would help if you'd also add the HTML (more than the empty div that is)

Comment: I just did now... However since it's a Sharepoint site, it's just showing the webparts being pulled :/

Comment: But the content loads right? So copy/paste the loaded HTML from your elements tab in the developer console (inspect element or F12).

Answer (score 0):

Use the `active` option of jQuery accordian.
[Active](http://api.jqueryui.com/accordion/#option-active)

```
 $("#accordion").accordion({ heightStyle: "content", active: 1/*The 2nd accordian*/ });
```